# Increase and Decrease values on Button click

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I want to show value on UIlabel. when I press UIbutton to increase or decrease values on label. This is my code and when I am running my project but I didn't get any value on my uilabel.

```
@IBAction func btnIncreaseAction(_ sender: Any) {


    var count = 0
    count = (count + 1)

   if let cell = (sender as? UIButton)?.superview?.superview?.superview as? ShoppingCell
    {
        //cell.lblForOnty.text = "\(cell.lblForOnty.text ?? 0 + 1)"
        cell.lblForOnty.text = String(count)
    }



}



  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellRID") as! ShoppingCell

    var someValue: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            cell.lblForOnty.text = "\(count)"
        }
    }

    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: can you show the button hierarchy in cell

Comment: is button increase in your cell only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code which should be in your `ViewController`. I am assuming that `numberOfSections` is 1 and in `numberOfRowsInSection` you are passing then number of rows you want. Else you need to modify this line : `let indexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)`.

```
var count = 0 // Count variable should be a global variable, you need it to decrease the value too.
@objc func increaseCounter(sender: UIButton) {
    //increase logic here
    count = (count + 1)
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    cell.lblForOnty.text = "\(count)"
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellRID") as! ShoppingCell

    // Add tag and action to your button
    cell.yourButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.yourButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(increaseCounter(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: good code but there is a little problem suppose i increase any cell value but when i increase other cell value the count does not start from 0, it is from increase value.

Comment: Yes, in that case you will have to manage value for every cell, here it was for a controller. @akbarkhan

Answer (score 2):

`superview?.superview?.superview` is pretty weird. Don't do that. A callback is more reliable.

In the subclass `ShoppingCell` create a callback and the `IBAction`s for in- and decrease . Connect the actions to the buttons

```
class ShoppingCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblForOnty: UILabel!

    var callback : ((Int)->())?

    var counter = 0 {
      didSet {
         lblForOnty.text = "\(count)"
      }
    }

    @IBAction func btnIncreaseAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        counter += 1
        callback?(counter)
    }

    @IBAction func btnDecreaseAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if counter > 0 { counter -= 1 }
        callback?(counter)
    }

}
```

In `cellForRow` pass the `counter` value to the cell and use the callback to update the model which is represented by `dataSource` and which is a custom struct or class containing a property `counter`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellRID", for: indexPath) as! ShoppingCell

    let item = dataSource[indexPath.row]
    cell.counter = item.counter
    cell.callback = ( newValue in
        item.counter = newValue
    }

    return cell
}
```

No hassle with superviews and index paths.

Answer (score 1):

Move you count variable outside of the function
Increment/decrement the count inside the function and reload the table or you can reload particular index as well.
PFB the code snipped

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: rowNumber, inSection: 0)
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation:   UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follows these step:

Step 1 :

create object class

```
class QuantityBO : NSObject{
var quantity      : Int?
}
```

step 2:
Create global array in your class

```
var arrQuantityList = [QuantityBO]()
```

step 3 :

Assign the value according to your number of cell
It may be change according to your api resonse

step 4:

In cellForRowAt method please write:

```
cell.lblQuantity.text = String(arrQuantityList[indexPath.row].quantity)
cell.yourBtnName.tag = indexPath.row
```

step 5:

On your button action

```
arrQuantityList[sender.tag].quantity = arrQuantityList[sender.tag].quantity + 1
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation:   UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
```

It may helps to you.hank you.