# cellforRowat: indexPath not returning correct value for text field

Tags: ios, swift

Unable to extract new value from custom cell in tableView following user adjustment.

I have a custom cell (of class `RoutineRowCell`) that includes 2 buttons and a text field that contains an 'integer' value. The buttons increase and decrease respectively the value in the text field by 1 each time they are pressed. I have registered this in the ViewController and on load this value is populated by a default value and displayed in a tableView. This all works correctly.

However, once the user has finished adjusting this number by pressing the buttons, I'm trying to use `cellforRowAt: Indexpath` to return the cell and then extract the new value and add it back into the datasource array.

The cell seems to be returned correctly, but it is not finding the new value from the returned cell so the datasource is not being updated What am I doing wrong?

```
@IBAction func addRowButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

//Extend the datasourceArray with new item containing default value.

        myRoutine.routineStepArray.append(myRoutine.routineStep1)

//update any changed values in the existing UITableView back to the class containing the datasourceArray i.e. myRoutine.routineStepArray.

        for row in 0...myRoutine.routineStepArray.count - 1 {



        if let cell = self.routineTable.dataSource?.tableView(self.routineTable, cellForRowAt: IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)) as? RoutineRowCell {
                let newBeatsInBar = cell.beatsInBar.text

                myRoutine.routineStepArray[row] = RoutineStep(beats: cell.beatsInBar.text!, note: cell.noteValue.text!, bars: cell.numberOfBars.text!)


            } else {

                fatalError("No cell found at [\(row), 0]")
            }
        }


        routineTable.reloadData()
}
```

Expected result is that the new values of the `beatsInbar` (of class `RoutineRowCell`) are saved back to the datasource array `(myRoutine.RoutineStepArray)`, a new row added and the complete table reloaded with the adjusted values of existing cells presented and a new cell with the default values presented.

What actually happens is that `newBeatsInBar` contains the old default values so when the table reloads the adjusted values are lost. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this IBAction is in controller or in cell?

Comment: **Never, never, never** call the data source method `tableView(_ tableView:cellForRowAt:)` yourself. The method is exclusively called by the framework and expects a dequeued cell to be returned. You are discouraged from manipulating the cell directly anyway. Synchronize the cell values with the model and get the data from the model.

Comment: @vadian How do you update the datasource to reflect changes in the UI then? The cell gets returned correctly using this method, so why not the value of the field?

Comment: Because it's **not** the expected cell in the table view. It's a new dequeued cell whose UI elements were updated from the model. Use callbacks to update the model when the UI elements are modified by the user.

Comment: For example see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51396443/increase-and-decrease-values-on-button-click/51396879#51396879

Answer (score 0):

try changing line

```
`if let cell = self.routineTable.dataSource?.tableView(self.routineTable, cellForRowAt: IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)) as? RoutineRowCell`
```

with

```
if let cell = tableView(self.routineTable, cellForRowAt: IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)) as? RoutineRowCell
```

**EDIT**

altrenatively, you can update values in your data array when increase and decearse buttons are clicked in respective row. to identify the buttons, you can set the tag to buttons as indexPath.row. and simply use tag value to update data in respective index in your data source.

Comment: I did use that method initially, but the cell was returning as nil. The  method I used was suggested by someone on here, and does appear to work correctly...

Comment: @MissHighwater have updated my answer for alternative approach, let me know if its unclear